# Alternative to an application server

Tags: jakarta-ee, osgi, websphere-8, vert.x

I'm a Java EE developer and have been part of a project for some time. The application is nothing else but a cache. It loads data via EJBs / RMI from the backend, stores it to a database via JPA and offers SOAP webservices to the frontend applications to access the data in this database. The application itself as well as all the whole backend are Java EE applications run on Websphere servers.

My problem with this setup is that it is heavyweight and in my eyes to hard to maintain. Now, trying to figure out the lessons learnt I would like to know what kind of alternatives there are - for the whole application design or parts of it. I would like to know from you which technologies are used in (working) enterprise solutions solving my problems in 2014:

- Running an OSGi based bus whereas the mapping is made by example with Apache Camel including EJB access?
- Using technolgies for the services to the frontend like vert.x?
- Spring as a replacement of Java EE and Tomcat as an alternative for Websphere?
- Using technology based on scripting langugages like python omiting a server?
- ...

Thanks for your suggestions.
Regards

Comment: As alternative to Tomcat you can consider [WebSphere Liberty Profile](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/introducing_the_liberty_profile/). It is as lightweight as Tomcat, but you can enable features that you need (like JAX-RS, EJB lite, JPA) without nightmare of finding and matching different libraries, as they are provided and tested. It is certified Java EE web profile. Using Tomcat has less sens as you have to actually build server by your self and fight with any library incompatibilities.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anyone in the consulting company I work for has deployed a new application to a Big Name, shared application server in the last five years or so. Virtualization displaced the app server as the app-to-iron multiplexer, and those VMs are now being displaced by Docker containers. Apps embed their own HTTP stack, which may be Tomcat, but increasingly it's asynchronous stacks because one-thread-per-socket inhibits scalability.

If we were to build an API translator, fetch-and-forward system like you describe today, it would most likely be in Scala with Akka and Spray, optionally sitting behind Nginx. There exist intriguing alternatives, e.g. in Clojure, but this is the stack with which we're most familiar. I don't know if we've used vert.x, but it would fit in this space.

We don't use SOAP much if at all anymore. Same for Spring Framework and Hibernate.

The application's local datastore may not be an RDBMS. I don't know the full requirements of your system. It sounds like it's been around for a while, so while you describe it as "just a cache", I would guess it's more complex than that. Depending on the context, we've deployed memcached, Redis, GemFire, MongoDB, Riak or indeed PostgreSQL.

Comment: We use that approach, except that we deploy an OSS Java EE AS to docker, with of course a single application only. I could care less about the ability of the AS to run multiple apps, but the Java EE programming model is just to good to give up (and frankly there's no need for it)